# How to subclass a gui control?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, gdi

I'm trying to learn how to subclass a GUI control and 'modify' its `hdc`.

This is my `subclass callback`:

mygui.h

```
#include <commctrl.h> // SetWindowSubclass
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")

#include <windows.h> // GDI includes.
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
using namespace DllExports;
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")



typedef UCHAR GuiControls;
enum GuiControlTypes {
    GUI_CONTROL_BUTTON
};

struct GuiControlOptionsType
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    LPCWSTR text;
    GuiControlTypes controltype;

    bool ERASEDBKGND = false; // Used on the subclass proc.
    HDC dc;
};

class Gui
{
public:
    std::map<HWND, GuiControlOptionsType> control_list;
    HWND GuihWnd;
    HWND A_LasthWnd;
    LRESULT Create();
    LRESULT AddControl(GuiControls aControlType, GuiControlOptionsType opt);
};

LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);
```

mygui.cpp

```
/* Window Procedure. */
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // TODO
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    Gui mygui;
    mygui.Create();
}

LRESULT Gui::Create()
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc{};
    MSG Msg;
    HWND hWnd = nullptr;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX); wc.style = 0; wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc; wc.cbClsExtra = 0; wc.cbWndExtra = 0; 
    wc.hInstance = 0; wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW); wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1); wc.lpszMenuName = NULL; 
    wc.lpszClassName = L"classname";

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
        // TODO

    this->GuihWnd = CreateWindowW(
        wc.lpszClassName,
        L"Title",
        WS_EX_COMPOSITED | WS_EX_LAYERED | // Double buffering
        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 200,
        nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    if (this->GuihWnd == NULL)
        // TODO

    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    GuiControlOptionsType opt;
    opt.x = 10; opt.y = 10; opt.width = 100; opt.height = 100; opt.text = L"test";
    this->AddControl(GUI_CONTROL_BUTTON, opt);
    SetWindowSubclass(this->A_LasthWnd, ButtonProc, 1, (DWORD_PTR)this);

    ShowWindow(this->GuihWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(this->GuihWnd);

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    return 0; // Msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT Gui::AddControl(GuiControls aControlType, GuiControlOptionsType opt)
{
    switch (aControlType)
    {
    case GUI_CONTROL_BUTTON:
    {
        HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
            L"BUTTON",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
            opt.text,   // Button text 
            WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
            opt.x,          // x position 
            opt.y,          // y position 
            opt.width,      // Button width
            opt.height,     // Button height
            this->GuihWnd,  // Parent window
            NULL,           // No menu.
            NULL,           //(HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
            NULL);          // Pointer not needed.

        opt.controltype = GUI_CONTROL_BUTTON;
        this->control_list.emplace(hWnd, opt);
        this->A_LasthWnd = hWnd;
    }
    break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return 1;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    Gui* pThis = (Gui*)dwRefData;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
    {
        if (pThis->control_list[hWnd].ERASEDBKGND)
            return 1;

        // Create/save the new button dc.
        GpBitmap* pBitmap;
        GdipCreateBitmapFromScan0(pThis->control_list[hWnd].width, pThis->control_list[hWnd].height, 0, PixelFormat32bppPARGB, 0, &pBitmap);

        GpGraphics* g;
        GdipGetImageGraphicsContext(pBitmap, &g);
        GdipGraphicsClear(g, 0xFF2400ff);

        HBITMAP hbm;
        GdipCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap(pBitmap, &hbm, 0);

        HDC dc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
        SelectObject(dc, hbm);

        pThis->control_list[hWnd].dc = dc;

        GdipDisposeImage(pBitmap);
        GdipDeleteGraphics(g);
        DeleteObject(hbm);

        pThis->control_list[hWnd].ERASEDBKGND = 1;
    }
    break;

    case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, 1);
    }
    break;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        BLENDFUNCTION bf;
        bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
        bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
        bf.BlendFlags = 0;
        bf.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

        GdiAlphaBlend(hdc, 0, 0, pThis->control_list[hWnd].width, pThis->control_list[hWnd].height,
            pThis->control_list[hWnd].dc, 0, 0, pThis->control_list[hWnd].width, pThis->control_list[hWnd].height, bf);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        DeleteObject(hdc);
        return TRUE;
    }
    break;

    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The problem is... when I click on the button it restores its default `hdc`, when I minimize/restore it draws with my 'custom' `hdc`.

[image]

I tried adding a call to `InvalidateRect()` under `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, but it resulted in the same thing.

I also tried creating the `Gui` with 'double buffering' adding the styles `WS_EX_COMPOSITED | WS_EX_LAYERED`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just to clarify, by "subclass" are you referring to [Win32 Window Subclassing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview), or C++ Subclassing?

Comment: I see you have a Win32 Message Pump in your `Gui::Create()` method - that doesn't seem right to me: there only needs to be a single message-pump in an application and it shouldn't belong to any particular GUI component: [usually it's in your `WinMain`  function](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050422-08/?p=35813).

Comment: The button control draws when it feels like it, not only via `WM_PAINT`. Use the mechanism provided for this by the OS by responding to `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` notification messages.

Comment: @Dai I've moved it to the `WinMain`, about your previous question, i don't know tell the difference between the two. There's something else that could be 'better' to change/modify?

Comment: @Juliete They're entirely separate concepts...

Comment: I wonder if storing the `control hwnd`/`'options'` could be done differently than using a `map` like i'm doing.

Comment: The `CreateWindow` call is wrong. It's passing [extended window styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles) reinterpreted as [window styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles). You'll need to call [`CreateWindowExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexw) if you want to set extended window styles. That may be unrelated to your immediate issue but will at least work towards a baseline implementation that's not obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`BS_OWNERDRAW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-styles#BS_OWNERDRAW) should be "her" style, I think.

Comment: Thank you, adding this style looks like it's working great now.

Comment: Not entirely sure here, but I believe this appears to work by coincidence rather than being the actual solution. The `BS_OWNERDRAW` flag instructs the button control to have its parent render the control as appropriate. The parent, now, simply ignores handling those messages, making the device context appear to remain intact. If I'm wrong, and this is indeed how you'd solve this, the button control's window procedure would at least need to handle `WM_NCPAINT` as well. Though you're losing vital information (such as hovering or whether the control is currently focused).